# How to transform networkx data into pytorch-geometric Data?

Tags: python-3.x, graph, pytorch, networkx, pytorch-geometric

How to load networkx list of graphs into pytorch-geometric Data using torch_geometric.utils.convert.from_networkx() ? There are only graph level labels are available.

Comment: Can you show what you have already tried?